# How to tell gcc to not to optimize specific function

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list

I have a function like this;

```
/* Swap two element by address*/
static __inline void dllist_swap_byaddress(void *elem1, void *elem2) {

    /*
    Modify pointers to swap order of elements. Consider swapping by value
    if data to be swapped is smaller than 8 bytes or so.
    */

    void *elem1_prev = dllist_getprev(elem1);
    void *elem1_next = dllist_getnext(elem1);
    void *elem2_prev = dllist_getprev(elem2);
    void *elem2_next = dllist_getnext(elem2);

    __dllist_setnext(elem2_prev, elem1);
    __dllist_setnext(elem1_prev, elem2);
    __dllist_setnext(elem1, elem2_next);
    __dllist_setnext(elem2, elem1_next);

}
```

But, it doesn't work as expected. I am guessing (I don't know how to verify it though), that gcc optimizes my code into this:

```
__dllist_setnext(dllist_getprev(elem2), elem1);
__dllist_setnext(dllist_getprev(elem1), elem2);
__dllist_setnext(elem1, dllist_getnext(elem2));
__dllist_setnext(elem2, dllist_getnext(elem1));
```

However, I don't want this to happen because `__dllist_setnext(dllist_getprev(elem2), elem1)` for example, also change's value of `dllist_getprev(elem1)`. That is the whole reason I am trying to save them in local stack in the first place.

How can I verify that gcc actually does it or not, and if it does, how can I tell it to stop doing it?

I have tried to make `void *`'s volatile, but I had to cast them into void* again before calling the function, and I don't think it made any difference.

Comment: Before looking at micromanaging optimizations, how about compiling the whole program with optimization disabled (`-O0`) to see whether that resolves the problem?  If it does not (as is my prediction) then optimization is not your problem.

Comment: Note, too, that it is highly unlikely that GCC is performing the optimization you describe.  It will not reorder function calls unless it can prove that it's safe to do so (or thinks it can).  It is far more likely to fail to prove that despite it being true, than to erroneously think it can prove it.

Comment: In fact, if your function/macro names are any indication of what they actually do, I can pretty confidently say that it's your code that's broken, not the compiler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It is a logic error? I checked the logic twice, but it is late night here, I might have missed something.

Comment: Consider what happens when `elem1` is immediate predecessor or successor of `elem2`.

Comment: Compilers do have bugs, but they are *almost never* the reason your program (or mine) doesn't work.  Always start by assuming otherwise.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ohh, I just figured out my error, data's next and prev points to itself :/

Answer (score 1):

*How to tell gcc to not to optimize specific function*

You can use `optimize` function attribute to compile a function with different optimization options.

From `gcc` [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

> optimize
>
> The optimize attribute is used to specify that a function is to be compiled with different optimization options than specified on the command line. Arguments can either be numbers or strings. Numbers are assumed to be an optimization level. Strings that begin with O are assumed to be an optimization option, while other options are assumed to be used with a -f prefix. You can also use the ‘#pragma GCC optimize’ pragma to set the optimization options that affect more than one function. See Function Specific Option Pragmas, for details about the ‘#pragma GCC optimize’ pragma.